# C# Application gives an error when trying to delete MySQL rows more than once

Tags: c#, mysql-connector

I have created a database in MySQL and an application in C# for said database for data entry.
The aplication works fine except when i try to delete rows.
The first time around it works fine but if i try to do it again i get "Parameter @titleID has already been defined"

Here is the complete code i have

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.StartPanel;

namespace media_database
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MySqlConnection sqlConn = new MySqlConnection();
        MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand();
        DataTable sqlDT = new DataTable();
        String sqlQuery;
        MySqlDataAdapter DtA = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        MySqlDataReader sqlRd;

        DataSet DS = new DataSet();

        String server = "localhost";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "pass";
        String database = "games";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void uploadData()
        {
            sqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=" + server + ";"
                + "user =" + user + ";"
                + "password =" + password + ";"
                + "database =" + database;
            sqlConn.Open();
            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "select * from games.games";
            sqlRd = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            sqlDT.Load(sqlRd);
            sqlRd.Close();
            sqlConn.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = sqlDT;
        }

        private void barCodeNum()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int num = rnd.Next(0, 10000);
            txtBarCode.Text ="Ref test" + Convert.ToString(num * 8);
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void panel5_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DialogResult iExit;

                iExit = MessageBox.Show("Confirm if you want to exit" , "GamesDB" , MessageBoxButtons.YesNo , MessageBoxIcon.Question);

                if (iExit == DialogResult.Yes) 
                    {
                        Application.Exit();
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
        }

        private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       
            {
                try
                {
                foreach (Control c in panel3.Controls)
                    {
                        if (c is TextBox)
                        {
                            ((TextBox)c).Clear();
                        }
                    }
                    txtBarCode.Clear();
                    txtSearch.Clear();
                    cboScore.Text = "";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            barCodeNum();
            uploadData();
        }

        private void btnAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                sqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=" + server + ";"
                + "user =" + user + ";"
                + "password =" + password + ";"
                + "database =" + database;

                sqlConn.Open();
                sqlQuery = "insert into games.games(titleID, title,year,genre," +
                    "developer,publisher,score)" +
                "values('" + txtID.Text + "', '" + txtTitle.Text + "', '" + txtYear.Text + "', '" +
                txtGenre.Text + "', '" + txtDev.Text + "', '" + txtPub.Text + "', '" +
                cboScore.Text + "')";
                sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn);
                sqlRd = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            finally { sqlConn.Close();}
            uploadData();
            barCodeNum();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                txtID.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                txtTitle.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                txtYear.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                txtGenre.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                txtDev.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                txtPub.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                cboScore.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
             
            }
        }

        private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataView dataView = sqlDT.DefaultView;
                dataView.RowFilter = string.Format("title like '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dataView.ToTable();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                sqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=" + server + ";"
                    + "user =" + user + ";"
                    + "password =" + password + ";"
                    + "database =" + database;

                sqlConn.Open();

                sqlCmd.CommandText = "delete from games.games where titleID = @titleID";

                
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titleID", txtID.Text);
                
                int rowsAffected = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (rowsAffected > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Record deleted successfully.", "Delete Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No matching record found for deletion.", "Delete Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
              
                sqlConn.Close();

                btnReset_Click(sender, e);

                foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                sqlQuery = "select * from games.games where titleID = '" + txtSearch.Text + "'";
                sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn);
                sqlRd = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (sqlRd.Read()) 
                {
                    txtID.Text = sqlRd.GetString("titleID");
                    txtTitle.Text = sqlRd.GetString("title");
                    txtYear.Text = sqlRd.GetString("year");
                    txtGenre.Text = sqlRd.GetString("genre");
                    txtDev.Text = sqlRd.GetString("developer");
                    txtPub.Text = sqlRd.GetString("publisher");
                    cboScore.Text = sqlRd.GetString("score");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data not found","MySQL connector",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }

                sqlConn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tried to delete an entry and then delete another entry.

Comment: Don't just make one MySqlConnection/MySqlCommand/etc object for your form. Thanks to conneciton pooling, every query you run really should have it's own connection, ideally created and disposed as part of a `using` block.

Comment: Also, it's **NEVER** okay to use string concatenation to put data into an SQL query like that. It is, though, a _great_ way to get your app hacked. The INSERT statement in the AddNew function is especially egregious. The Search function is bad, too.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're using the same `MySqlCommand` object for the entire lifetime of the form. *This is bad.*

I know it seems inefficient to re-allocate these objects, but thanks to **connection pooling** you should create — and dispose — brand new ADO.Net objects (especially the connection) for every query, ideally as part of a `using` block. *Really*. If you want to re-use something, build the connection string in one place and re-use that.

Do this, and the problem that the query parameter is already defined will go away as a matter of course.

On the other hand, you *could* instead call `sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();` in the delete function, but this is the lesser fix verses using the ADO.Net objects the right way in the first place.

---

While I'm here, that you see this error at all indicates some awareness of parameterized queries... so **why in the name of God** do I still see string concatenation everywhere else? This is such a very very bad practice. **NEVER** use string concatenation to substitute user input into an SQL string. *Every single one of those* should also be a query parameter. I can't understate how important it is to do this the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Please refactor ALL your code. the error is because you have defined Sql related properties and class level so everytime you add/delete it tries to add the parameter however it exists.

consider usage of Using on C# to ensure the correct disposal of objects.